# How to get rid of numbers in the String?

Tags: java, regex

I have a very long String. I need to get rid of numbers there

```
And we're never gonna
bust out of our cocoons

65
00:03:04,113 --> 00:03:06,815
- if we don't put our busts out there.
- Nice metaphor.

66
00:03:06,833 --> 00:03:09,418
And we can just go to
the piano bar and not sing
   ............
```

I need it to be

```
And we're never gonna
bust out of our cocoons

- if we don't put our busts out there.
- Nice metaphor.

And we can just go to
the piano bar and not sing
```

I tried the following

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("\d+\n\d","");
```

Comment: Use a character class. the square brackets

Comment: You should be clear on your requirement.  You said you want to get rid of numbers, then why the `: -->` etc are also removed? What is the actual rule you want? Remove something if it start and end with number? Remove the line if it contains no alphabet? or it should only be removed if it follow the exact format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like

```
myString = myString.replaceAll("(?m)^([\\s\\d:,]|-->)+$", "");
```

This regex will search for lines (character between start of line `^` and end of line `$`) that are either

- `\\s` spaces
- `\\d` digits
- `:`
- `,`
  or
- `-->`

`(?m)` is "*multiline*" flag used to let `^` and `$` be start or end of each line, instead of entire string.

Comment: I am not sure if `.............` is part of your string or not so didn't included it in answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String pattern = "[0-9]+\n[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9] "
      + "--> [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]\n";
  String in = "And we're never gonna\n"
      + "bust out of our cocoons\n\n65\n"
      + "00:03:04,113 --> 00:03:06,815\n"
      + "- if we don't put our busts out there.\n"
      + "- Nice metaphor.\n\n66\n"
      + "00:03:06,833 --> 00:03:09,418\n"
      + "And we can just go to\n"
      + "the piano bar and not sing";
  in = in.replaceAll(pattern, "\n").replace("\n\n",
      "\n");
  System.out.println(in);
}
```

Which outputs

```
And we're never gonna
bust out of our cocoons

- if we don't put our busts out there.
- Nice metaphor.

And we can just go to
the piano bar and not sing
```

Comment: Nice and comprehensive